# Increase every number in hml code by integer X

Tags: html, editor

I have a static HTML page with a LOT of form field placed on an image. I was now handed a new image, where every field was moved 3px down.

How do I multiselect all "top: xyz" tags in the file and add 3 to each? I am currently using notepad++, sublime and phpstorm, based on my needs, but am very ok with downloading another for this purpose.

Example fields may look like this:

```
<input [disabled_customer_0_Nr] class="basic inputfield" type="text" id="input_customer_0_Nr" tabindex="13" value="[customer_0_Nr_Value]" title="" name="customer_0_Nr" style="position: absolute;left: 365px;top: 772px; height: 19px; width: 125px;">
```

or

```
<input [disabled_car_0_name] class="basic inputfield" type="text" id="input_car_0_name" tabindex="13" value="[car_0_name_Value]" title="" name="car_0_name" style="position: absolute;left: 12px;top: 1234px; height: 19px; width: 15px;">
```

Comment: Can you post an example ?

Comment: Do all the "top: xyz" have three degits ? do they have different values ?
If all have three degits i can help you with some shortcuts in VSCode

Comment: Unfortunately they all have between two and four digits and therefore have different values as well. They don't have many similarities, except the way they are placed with top: and left:

Comment: Edit your question and post your example code there

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: Do you want to replace all the top tags with +3 of that or something else?

Comment: and all of them are enclosed in input tag having same class = "basic inputfield" ?

Comment: Either input tag with "basic inputfield", or div with "basic dropdownfield". And yes, only top tags need to be replaced and with their former value + 3

Comment: @Rufrage check the below answer using JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this case should be covered by script, most probably JavaScript for the available tooling around it. But, I am a lazy person and i love IDEs shortcuts. Here is my solution:
You can use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to help you with this.
Taking your use case:

- All fields start with "top:"
- You have different values and each value vary from 2 to 4 digits.

**Assumption**: I hope you have a height property with single space after each "top: xyz". If this is not the case the commands below will not help.

After installing VSCode, Open your file check that [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) is there using Ctrl + Shift + P and type Emmet. If you can find commands there then we are fine. Now:

1. Select a single "top:" using mouse.
2. Use Ctrl + D to select duplicates.
3. Move the cursor in front of "top:" using the right arrow.
4. Hit some spaces and write "3 +"
5. Hit Escape to return to a single cursor mode.
6. Now select a single "px; h" in front of a random "top:   3+ xyz" using mouse.
7. Use Ctrl + D to select duplicates.
8. Move the cursor back using left arrow.
9. Select all the numbers using Shift + left arrow ( "3+ xyz").
10. Press Ctrl + Shift + P to open command menu and type "Math".
11. Chose "Emmet: Evaluate Math Expression" and hit Enter.

    And there, the magic happens. Emmet will evaluate the numeric expression and replace it with the result value.

**PS**: Another solution would be using CSS `calc()` instead of providing static values.

Answer (score 1):

There you go!

Apply this JQuery code to your html file, it will do the rest for you.

```
$('.inputfield').css('top', '+='+3 +'px');

$('.dropdownfield').css('top', '+='+3 +'px');
```

where inputfield & dropdownfield are your input tag classes

Comment: This solution works very well for the question I asked!
However, i need the magic to happen in the code itself, instead of afterwards, because a very few fields may not look good with +3, but with +2 or +4 instead. This way I can recalculate all of them and manually fix only the few remaining. Awesome leightweight solution besides that!